# How do create table and load data to it from file | PLSQL |

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been trying a long time not getting how do I need to implement it.

I have table called as `employee` but this is in other DB link called as `demo2`.

Currently granted DB : `demo1` an access to table in `demo2` via **DB Link setup**.

**Below is the table structure in** `demo2`

```
create employee 
(
  empid number,
  empname varchar2(30)
);
```

Using SQL I am able to create same table at `demo1.employee` taking reference of `demo2.employee` table
Empty table created

`create table demo1.employee as select * from demo2.employee@XYZ_DB_LINK`

**I have a file which is in blob in table**

```
create table temp as SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(
         APEX_DATA_PARSER.parse(
           p_content         => (select fblob from temp where id=12),
           p_file_name       => 'emp.csv',
           p_add_headers_row => 'N',
           p_skip_rows       => 0  
         )
       );
```

The issue is table is getting created with `line_number , c001 , c002` -> columns but not with actual columns like demo2.employee table columns.

Note : emp.csv file as headers

Below data in emp.csv file

```
empid,empname
1,ABC
2,AXD
3,XYZ
4,FGH
```

I want to consider the headers in file and dynamically my table should be created. So that from temp table I can push to demo1.employee table the data

`temp -> demo1.employee -> demo2.employee`

```
insert into demo1.employee as select * from temp;
```

but due to `line_number , cool, cool2` its not possible

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Do you know such a tool like SQL Loader? It's purpose is exactly what you neeed - to load the data from filedirectly into the table

Comment: @ekochergin : I don't have that and I cannot install also. Need to use only PLSQL & SQL

Comment: okay, understood. Using your dev environment (SQL Dveloper, PLSQL Developer) is not an option as well?

Comment: *[PARSE Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html#GUID-B815CF74-C469-4F78-9433-643D1339E930): This is the main parser function. It allows to parse XML, XLSX, CSV or JSON files and returns a generic table of the following structure:
`LINE_NUMBER COL001 COL002 COL003 COL004 ... COL300`
All values are returned in VARCHAR2 format. A returned table row can have a maximum of 300 columns. The maximum length for a table column is 4000 bytes; there is no line length maximum*

Comment: This is because Oracle should be able to determine columns and datatypes at parsing stage to perform semantic checks

Comment: @memotib827, sqlloader comes with the Oracle client. That is the correct tool to use. You could write a program in any number of languages that have an Oracle client driver, but it doesn't sound like that's an option for you either. You cannot load data in a responsible manner using SQL, and definitely not using PL/SQL (that doesn't even make sense).

Comment: While you could script a bunch of insert statements, you'd be shredding the shared pool by inserting literals, each insert being a unique sqlid requiring its own associated cursor memory. If this is a one-time load of a few thousand records, then go ahead - script some inserts using Excel or something. But if you're trying to write a repeatable app process, you don't have the right tools.

Comment: @PaulW External Tables are a preferred method to SQL Loader. That allows you to use SQL. ANd if you are loading large data volumes, you can use parallelism

Comment: External tables have the extreme limitation that they can only load data visible to the database instance, which means the filesystem the files are on must be mounted by the database host. In most companies, application servers are strictly separated from database servers, so this often does not work. SQL*Loader is for this reason usually the only way (well, the only sane way, there is a crazy workaround with the PREPROCESSOR option and ssh channeling, but that's getting into voodoo) to get files from somewhere else into an Oracle database using Oracle's own packaged tools.

Comment: (You can also use sqlplus but that'll make a total mess of your shared pool , is ugly and performs horridly). SQL*Loader has been around for decades and is still and excellent tool very much in use today. There's been no clear replacement for it to date, without going to 3rd party tools or writing your own.